# Microsoft Excel cannot paste the data. FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Tags: excel, powershell, windows-scripting, comobject, excel.application

So I have a PowerShell script which copies the data from an source xls file to a destination xlsx file.
Assume I have file named "3 ABC01.xls" and I have to insert the data present in this xls file into an sheet named ABC01 in the destination file xlsx. So I have written the following logic

```
$csvFilePath = Read-Host "Enter the CSV File path"
$data = Import-Csv -Path $csvFilePath
$startRowNumber = 5
$firstRowNumber = 5
$lastRowNumber = 15


$destExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$destExcel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$destExcel.Visible = $false
$destWorkbook = $destExcel.Workbooks.Open("destination.xlsx")
foreach ($line in $data) {
    $column1 = $line.column1
    $column2 = $line.column2
    
    $tamlineString = $column1 + " " + $column2
    $sourceFilePath = "$downloadDirectory\$column1\$tamlineString.xls"
    
    $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
    $excel.Visible = $false
    $sourceWorkbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($sourceFilePath)
    $sourceWorksheet = $sourceWorkbook.Sheets.Item(1)
    
    $worksheetName = $column2 + $sheet
    Write-Host $worksheetName
    $destWorksheet = $destWorkbook.Sheets.Item($worksheetName)

    
    # Loop through the rows to copy and insert
    for ($i = $lastDateRowNumber - 1; $i -ge $firstRowNumber; $i--) {
        $sourceRange = $sourceWorksheet.Rows.Item($i)
        # Copy the source row
        $sourceRange.Copy() | Out-Null
        # Insert a new row in the destination worksheet
        $destWorksheet.Rows.Item($startRow).Insert() | Out-Null
        
        # Get the newly inserted row
        $destRow = $destWorksheet.Rows.Item($startRow) 
        
        # Paste values and formatting from the clipboard
        $destRow.PasteSpecial(-4163) | Out-Null  # -4163 represents 'Paste All' in Excel
        [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($destRow) | Out-Null
        $destRow = $null
    }

    
    # Close and quit the source workbook
    #$sourceWorksheet.Close()
    $destWorkbook.Save()
    $sourceWorkbook.Close()
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sourceWorksheet)| Out-Null
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sourceWorkbook)| Out-Null

    # Quit Excel application
    $excel.Quit()
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)| Out-Null
    
    Write-Host "Rows copied and inserted successfully for $column1 $column2."
}

$destWorkbook.Save()
$destWorkbook.Close()

[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($destWorksheet) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($destWorkbook) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($destExcel) | Out-Null
```

And I am running the above code, and getting the below exception inconsistently, like sometimes I get the exception and sometimes I dont get the exception.

```
Microsoft Excel cannot paste the data.
At D:\Users\Shyam\script.ps1:37 char:17
+                 $destRow.PasteSpecial(-4163) | Out-Null  # -4163 repr ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

I am not able to get why am I getting this exception? Can anyone help me in explaining what is going on? Thank you!! for your time

I tried adding the extra `Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100` inside the for loop before copying the data after inserting the row, etc.. but again I was getting the same error.

I am expecting to run this script and it should not give me the exception while running the script. It should successfully paste the data.

Comment: You have XLS, not XLSX (excel).  XLSX is a proprietary binary file while XLS is Text.

Comment: Hello @jdweng, I have modified the $destWorkbook variable, so if there was any confusion now it might have resolved, So I want to transfer the data from XLS file to XLSX file. I am sorry if I didnt got what you mean, can you please explain in detail what you meant?

Comment: Do not mix xls and xlsx they are not the same.  Your variable $startRow is not initialized.

Comment: .xls is a binary file. Try `Format-Hex -Path the.xls`. .xlsx is a text file. It was created to represent XML in order to convince potential customers, especially in the EU, that it was not proprietary and was open to interoperating with other software. Has it worked out that way?

Comment: Have you tried the same sequence *manually*? You might be trying to paste into merged cells for example, and the UI may give a better error message than the COM interface does…

Comment: Yes I do have tried operating it manually, it works fine, the script also works fine but sometimes it gives the exception that I mentioned above. @mclayton

Comment: Yes, the code that I wrote is working fine for transferring the data, as I expected, but sometimes and inconsistently it gives the exception that I mentioned above - @lit

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to initialize I have modified my code and now I have initialized the undeclared variables, in my actual script, I have different functions that calculate the value of $startRow, $firstRowNumber and $lastDateRowNumber , these are basically integers, we can take them as constant for this example as :
$startRowNumber = 5
$firstRowNumber = 5
$lastRowNumber = 15

Modified the original code as well. @jdweng.

Comment: Does worksheet have any merged cells?  Paste errors usually occur when a worksheet has merged cells.

Comment: okay, got it, yes it does have several merged cells, but I am not getting why this errors happen inconsistently, sometimes it does not give me error at all and sometimes it only gives me the exception that I mentioned, do you have any idea how to deal with this issue? @jdweng

Comment: The pasted area has to fit inside the area where pasted.  The upper left cell is used as the  location to paste.  When the pasted area is smaller than the location that it is pasted is when the error usually occurs.

Comment: No I made sure that this does not happen, because in the destination sheet, the number of columns are same as source sheet, and the data corresponding in both the excel sheet are same, any other suggestion that I can try?